# Sentence from Seneca's Consolation to Helvia

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

In Consolation to Helvia, a letter Seneca wrote to his mother while in exile, the English translation says:

> I don't have doubt that I shall have more influence over you than your grief, than which nothing has more influence over the wretched.

(p. 40, On the Shortness of Life, Penguin, 2005)

I am not sure what he means exactly by adding that second part to the sentence. I understand the part before the comma: I will have more influence over you than your grief in my effort to console you. But the second part seems a bit odd. Does he mean it as a continuation of the first part, like he's saying that he will have more influence that anything might have over the wretched? Does he mean the wretched are easily influenced?

Comment: There's a different translation on [Wikisource,](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Of_Consolation:_To_Helvia) where the sentence reads "See how far I have presumed upon your indulgence: I have no doubts about my having more power over you than your grief, than which nothing has more power over the unhappy." This seems to imply that the contradiction was there in the original Latin (it's not a mistranslation), and that he's denying the truth of the first part of the sentence with it.

Comment: Wherein lies the contradiction? Sorry, that is a genuine question. You mean the two statements themselves are contradictory? So: _I will have more influence over you than your grief_ and _nothing has influence over the unhappy_? And this is meant to deny the first part of the sentence? Why would it be written that way?

Comment: I presume you mean *nothing has **more** influence over the unhappy* in your comment. The contradiction is between *I have more influence over you than your grief* and *grief has more influence over the wretched (i.e., you) than anything else (including me)*, where I've paraphrased the second part to highlight the contradiction.

Comment: I see that you didn't entirely understand the grammar of the sentence. The *than which* refers to grief, and the second part of the sentence says, when you put the antecedent in explicitly: *nothing has more influence over the wretched than grief.* Why would it be written that way? Maybe because it's a direct translation of the Latin, and this sentence is less awkward in Latin.

Comment: Ah your last comment clarified it. Indeed I misunderstood the grammar of the sentence. Thank you very much.